# HTTPS app can't link to HTTP stylesheet and chrome-control

Tags: https

We are new to SharePoint and started testing SharePoint 2013 Preview. We set up a external (provider-hosted) "app" which runs on HTTPS. We deployed the app to SharePoint which runs (default setup) on HTTP. THey both run well and the app can retrieve SharePoint data (CSOM).

**Problem:**
We can not use SharePoint's stylesheet nor the Chrome-control to get the SharePoint look and feel because the browser (Chrome) revokes that connection from the HTTPS website (=app) to a HTTP target (SharePoint CSS file for example).

Any ideas how to fix this? Do we need to run SharePoint in HTTPS? If so, how do we do this / get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does just sound like an browser issue not specifically a SharePoint one.  Almost any browser will balk at having mixed-content on a page, Chrome has been more aggressive of late at preventing mixed-content, insecure ssl.

You could hack chrome for all your users.

```
http://www.labnol.org/software/disable-insecure-content-in-google-chrome/20501/
```

Otherwise you are left enabling the SSL for a SharePoint site.

Not being up to scratch with 2013, it is probably similar to 2010,

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/03/configuring-a-sharepoint-website-to-allow-ssl-connections/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-enable-ssl-on-a-sharepoint-web-application.aspx